# Passing locale parameter over site URL on ActiveResource

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, default, activeresource

I am developing a Rails application and I want to use ActiveResource to send requests to a REST Server. The actual URL site of the server is:

```
http://foo.com/api-v1.0
```

The point is that for every communication to server I want to pass the current locale at the Rails application context. So valid URL calls are:

- http://foo.com/api-v1.0/en/people
- http://foo.com/api-v1.0/fr/people

e.t.c.

So, I am following the poor ActiveResource documentation and I define my resource class as follows:

```
class MyClass < ActiveResource::Base
  self.site = "http://foo.com/api-v1.0/:locale
end
```

And then on my application controller, I have something like this, for example when getting all people:

```
MyClass.all(:params => {:locale => I18n.locale})
```

which works ok.

The question is that controller code becomes very verbose. I repeatedly have to pass `:params => {:locale => I18n.locale}` on every resource that I am accessing.

In order to avoid that, I decided to have a base class that derives from ActiveResource::Base and override all resource accessing methods in such a way so that I can set the :locale. So the code becomes:

```
class MyBaseClass < ActiveResource::Base
  self.site = "http://foo.com/api-v1.0/:locale"

  def self.all
    super(:params => {:locale => I18n.locale})
  end
end

class MyClass < MyBaseClass
end
```

and in my application controller:

```
MyClass.all
```

is enough.

However, this puts a lot of verbosity and complexity on the `MyBaseClass`. I have to override all the methods of `ActiveResource::Base` to pass this `:locale`.

Any clue how could I do that more efficiently?

Thanks in advance

Panayotis

Answer (score 0):

You mention that `MyBaseClass` derives from `ActiveResource::Base`, but the code indicates `ActiveRecord::Base` - presumably, this is a typo.

Ensure that the application locale is set properly; in case it's useful to you, here's how I usually set up I18n for applications:

In `app/controllers/application_controller.rb`:

```
before_filter :set_locale

def set_locale
  I18n.locale = params[:locale] || I18n.default_locale
end

def default_url_options(options={})
  {
    :locale => I18n.locale
  }
end
```

and in `config/routes.rb`:

```
scope "/:locale" do
  # routes
end
```

Then, set `ActiveResource::Base.prefix` in a `before_filter` for the controller. `ActiveResource::Base.site` can also be set in the same place, or alternatively on the model. The model name (lowercased) is used by default as the resource at the specified site; these can be overridden with `ActiveResource::Base.element_name`. `ActiveResource::Base.prefix` can be used to prefix each of these resource-paths. Thus, one way of achieving your example, across the whole app (but this could instead be just one non-Application controller) would be:

In `app/controllers/application_controller.rb`:

```
before_filter :setup_activeresource

def setup_activeresource
  ActiveResource::Base.site = "http://foo.com/api-v1.0"
  ActiveResource::Base.prefix = "#{I18n.locale}/"
end
```

Experimentation indicates that this sets the locale correctly for each request, as well as directing to the correct remote-resource (nested under /:locale/).

Comment: Thanks for the correction on the typo. No. Your solution is not working, because it sets the site once. ```self.site= "...``` is not called every time a request is sent over to remote resource (REST) server.

Comment: Ah, I see - of course, what I suggested only got set once. I've corrected my above post.

Answer (score 0):

Provided you always want this behaviour everywhere you use ActiveResource in your app: overwrite the low-level **ActiveResource::Connection.request** method to plop in the locale string:

```
class ActiveResource::Connection
  alias :original_request :request
  def request(method, path, *arguments)
    original_request(method, changed_path, *arguments)
  end
end
```

Stick that in an initializer.

Your string replacement will vary, but this would work for your example:

```
1.9.2p290 :066 >   path = "http://foo.com/api-v1.0/people"
 => "http://foo.com/api-v1.0/people" 
1.9.2p290 :067 > locale = "fr"
 => "fr" 
1.9.2p290 :068 > changed_path = path.sub(/http:\/\/foo.com\/api-v1.0\//, "http://foo.com/api-v1.0/#{locale}/")
 => "http://foo.com/api-v1.0/fr/people"
```